# CentOS RPM remote repo - resource has expired

Tags: repository, artifactory, rpm

Artifactory v7.38.10

I have configure a remote repository to point at http://mirror.centos.org/centos/

Default settings other than:

1. Metadata Retrieval Cache Period (Sec) - 0
2. Metadata Retrieval Cache Timeout (Sec) - 30
3. Assumed Offline Period (Sec)  - 0
4. Missed Retrieval Cache Period (Sec) - 0

The first time I retrieve **8-stream/BaseOS/x86_64/os/repodata/repomd.xml** it works but after an indeterminate time it begins throwing "Resource has expired" messages when trying to download from the web interface.

The problems persists even if the file has been updated to a newer version on the remote repository.

Is my Artifactory instance fundamentally broken? Am I missing a trick?

Answer (score 0):

Is the artifact resolution being made through the remote-cache repositories by default?

Please refer to the following KB article, https://jfrog.com/knowledge-base/how-to-fix-404-error-resource-has-expired/